# Give the names of employees who are strictly older than any employee who lives in London.?

Tags: mysql

The question is based on NorthWind Database.

For the above question i am trying to find the answer but i am getting zero rows

```
select FirstName,LastName from employees
where City and BirthDate <
(
Select min(BirthDate) from employees where City='London'
);
```

after removing City

[output is like this with 3 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYd7X.jpg)

but from the table if we see one row is missing employee name laura callahan who is older than employees with id 7 and 9

[employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTMR5.jpg)

Comment: Why do you have `where City`?

Comment: Define 'strictly'

Comment: @Strawberry Presumably it means "not the same age". I.e. `<` versus `<=`.

Comment: @Barmar Surely 'older' implies 'not the same age' !?!?

Comment: 'one row is missing employee name laura callahan ' why is that a surprise birthdate is 1958 min birthdate for london is 1955 employee id = 5 buchanan

Comment: Thank you @ P.Salmon

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `City` in `WHERE City AND BirthDate < (...)`

It's treating `City` as a boolean value, which requires converting it to a number. Unless the city begins with a digit, it will convert to `0`, which is `FALSE`, so the combined condition fails.

```
select FirstName,LastName from employees
where BirthDate <
(
Select min(BirthDate) from employees where City='London'
);
```

Comment: Now after executing i am getting only 3 rows instead of 4 rows?

Comment: Update the question with sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `max` because `min` returns the date which is the most older. So inorder to get the list of people who are older than any London employee, then their age should be greater than the youngest person in London. Hence you need to use `max`

```
select FirstName,LastName
From employees
where BirthDate < (
    Select max(BirthDate) from employees
    where City='London'
);
```